# LED lighting using peltier modules

Tags: peltier

I want to use a peltier element to power some small test LEDs. The power source should be a TEC (thermal energy converters) or A TEG (thermal energy generators) element.

I see a lot of people that don't know what they're doing and it I want to ask this because it seems also like a frequent idea in the maker community (to power wearables, Arduinos, even wearables).

Since there is an order of magnitude difference in pricing - can I make this work with a TEC? it's an indication light, it doesn't have to work always, blinking would be fine. In fact, as a maker project/experiment this should be kept low cost.

Here's what I know and plan, keep in mind I'm a bleeding noob:

1. Since TEC1 elements are not intended to be used as power generators, these specs are unclear. From random videos I gather, sillily: A warm hand on a TEC1-12706 will give you ca 0.08V with unclear current. Assuming (sillily) linearity and avg. body temperature, it'd be in the range of .1V / °10C with unknown current.
2. from other semi related sources I gather I can use some current to increase the voltage (current to voltage converters), I'm assuming that I can transfer all overproduced current to voltage at some cost
3. Jule thief circuits let you access lower voltage output by collecting and then releasing it all together [and is described more precisely here](https://hackaday.com/2013/11/12/peltier-joule-thief-power-supply/)
4. TEG modules are described to be about 3x more efficient. The SP1848 module seems to give very roughly 1V/200mA per 20°C, a hand on the module on YouTube displays .5V (so roughly matches, not an order of magnitude difference but 5x)
5. a common LED uses ca 20mA and 2V. The SP1848 seems more affordable than any other TEG I found and may be an alternative.

My prediction is, using a TEC-12706, even with all the tricks in the world - I won't be able to light one LED using a candle, let's assume 40°C difference (.4V, unclear current).

Questions:

- Is this a waste of time and effort and one should rather spend more money on a more expensive TEG element (not listed here)?
- Is it advisable to start any experiment of this sort with the SP1848 module rather than the TEC1-12706?
- How much can I rely on current to voltage converters and joule thief circuits/modules to help me out, practically?

Comment: As a learning exercise with whatever TEC you can find, with a multimeter, thermometer, and an assortment of load resistors, it certainly won't be a waste of time as long as you don't expect to light anything very much. If you can get enough V to get a "Joule Thief" or energy harvesting boost converter started ... well done. And you might be surprised how bright 1 mA lights one of the more efficient LEDs. Then answer your own question with a comprehensive set of results.

Comment: I'll report back here with what I learned, in the hope that this will be useful for others